# ORDER BY id based on id inside IN

Tags: mysql, sql

How to ORDER BY id based on id inside IN

```
SELECT * 
FROM mall 
WHERE mall_id IN (3331083,33310110,3331080,33310107,33310119,3331410) 
      AND mall_status='1' LIMIT 50
```

the result should be :

1. 3331083
2. 33310110
3. 3331080
   ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT * FROM mall 
WHERE mall_id IN (3331083,33310110,3331080,33310107,33310119,3331410) 
  AND mall_status='1' 
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(mail_id, 3331083,33310110,3331080,33310107,33310119,3331410) 
LIMIT 50
```